# Google spreadsheets - Conditional based on cell color from another document

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

Is there any way how to tell what background color has got cell in another spreadsheet?
For example:

if(cellCollor(ID;range) = #FF00FF)

Is there any way how to do it?

Comment: Not with a formula, but you can with google apps script. What are you trying to accomplish? Can you provide an example of what you want? What have you tried?

Comment: Actually google app script was the thing I ran for.. Simple and effective way how to do even more things than I want to :D

I have two independent spreadsheets, one for my boss (where he change background colors for days where he want to have my team), and another for my team. In the first I have to write name of person who will be there, but the same name must be in second.. That is quite simple via IMPORTRANGE function. But I need to see in 2nd which cells have yellow background in the 1st table... 

Sooo... google app scripts solved it pretty well, also I am now able to write it to gcal